# Spring @Bean autowire() - fails the second (?) time

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Ok, so, I have a config class that creates two beans. They are defined as the following:

```
public class FileUploadConfiguration {

    public static final String UPLOAD_PREFIX = "file.upload";

    @Bean(name = "fileService", autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    @DependsOn("fileUploadPaths")
    @Autowired
    public CRUDFileService fileService(@Qualifier("fileUploadPaths") PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean fileUploadPaths) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> paths = Maps.fromProperties(fileUploadPaths.getObject());
        return new CRUDFileService(File.class.getName(), paths);
    }

    @Bean(name = "fileUploadPaths")
    public PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean fileUploadPaths(Environment environment) {
        PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean fileUploadPaths = new PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean();
        fileUploadPaths.setPrefix(UPLOAD_PREFIX);
        fileUploadPaths.setLocations(ResourceUtils.getActiveResources(environment));
        return fileUploadPaths;
    }
}
```

If I put breakpoints in both instantiations, the flow is the following:

1) **fileUploadPaths** is instantiated, and it looks correct to me.
[image]

2) **fileService** gets instantiated, but through the **postProcessPropertyValues** of **FileUploadConfiguration** bean creation.. this seems weird to me.
[image]

3) After that, I get an exception, because it seems Spring tries to create **fileService** again, but now through the **createBean**, and for some reason the @Qualifier on the parameter definition seems to be ignored.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'fileService' defined in class
>   x.y.z.FileUploadConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed
>   through constructor argument with index 0 of type
>   [a.b.c.PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean]: Ambiguous factory method argument
>   types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method
>   arguments?    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:735)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)

**NOTE:** This is fixed if I change **fileService** definition to the following:

```
@Bean(name = "fileService")
@DependsOn("fileUploadPaths")
@Autowired
public CRUDFileService fileService(@Qualifier("fileUploadPaths") PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean fileUploadPaths, AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> paths = Maps.fromProperties(fileUploadPaths.getObject());
    CRUDFileService crudFileService = new CRUDFileService(File.class.getName(), paths);
    factory.autowireBean(crudFileService);
    return crudFileService;
}
```

So, instead of letting Spring autowire my bean through **@Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)**, I simply autowire the **AutowireCapableBeanFactory** and autowire the **CRUDFileService** bean myself.

My question is: Why does such behavior happen? Am I using **@Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)** correctly? I've used it before like that and it worked like a charm, except I didn't autowire the bean method parameters like I did with this one.

Comment: Just for my clarification - is `PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean` a Spring Factory bean?

Comment: @BijuKunjummen yes - it extends AbstractFactoryBean<Properties>.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I see is that you are trying to inject a Spring `FactoryBean` as a dependency into another bean. `FactoryBean` is special though, it is a factory for a bean and the resulting bean is what you should inject into other objects.

So assuming that your dependency in `CRUDFileService` is a `Properties` class instead of the FactoryBean, if you are to try this, it should work cleanly:

```
public class FileUploadConfiguration {

    public static final String UPLOAD_PREFIX = "file.upload";

    @Bean(name = "fileService", autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    @Autowired
    public CRUDFileService fileService(@Qualifier("fileUploadPaths") Properties fileUploadPaths) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> paths = Maps.fromProperties(fileUploadPaths);
        return new CRUDFileService(File.class.getName(), paths);
    }

    @Bean(name = "fileUploadPaths")
    public PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean fileUploadPaths(Environment environment) {
        PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean fileUploadPaths = new PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean();
        fileUploadPaths.setPrefix(UPLOAD_PREFIX);
        fileUploadPaths.setLocations(ResourceUtils.getActiveResources(environment));
        return fileUploadPaths;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does removing the `autowire` (thus defaulting to `Autowire.NO`) and leaving the `PrefixedPropertyFactoryBean` as a parameter type work?

Comment: Hey @BijuKunjummen, what you said makes sense - that I should be injecting the object the factory creates, not the factory itself while creating beans. But it doesn't fix, I now get the same exception but with Properties instead: **Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Properties]: Ambiguous factory method argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method arguments?**